# How to search exact phrase from a file which consist of set of phrase with hyphen

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, grep

I have the file, which consists of a couple of phrases as follows. I would like to grep the exact match from out of them.

***file.txt***

```
abc
abc-def
xyz
xyz-pqr
pqrs
```

If I search "**abc**" I need to return only **abc**.
or
if I search "**abc-def**" i need to return only "**abc-def**"

***preferd output***

```
$grep -w "abc" file.txt
abc
```

or

```
$grep -w "abc-def" file.txt
abc-def
```

the below method is **not working** for the **hyphens**

```
$grep -w abc file.txt
```

Comment: "word" characters are numbers, letters and underscore. Hyphen is a non-word character, which explains this grep behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your given data/file you can use the `-x` flag.

```
grep -x abc file.txt
```

---

```
grep -x abc-def file.txt
```

---

- -x, --line-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole lines
- The `-x` flag is defined/required by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) `grep`(1)

Answer (score 1):

In order to match an entire line you need to match the start and end of the line:

```
grep '^abc$' file.txt
grep '^abc-def$' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` this way:

```
awk -v w="abc" '$1==w' file.txt
abc
```

Or,

```
awk '$1==w' w="abc" file.txt
```

With the `==` operator, it only returns exact string matches. We are setting what to match with `w="abc"` either with the `-v` switch or through stdin.